# How to use chodorowicz / ts-debounce?

Tags: angular, typescript, algorithm, function, debouncing

I wanted to use function debounce from this package ts-debounce https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-debounce. But could not find an example on how to use it in typescript. Can anyone help? really appreciate. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like:

```
function originalFunction() {
    console.log('window resized')
}
                                // originalFunction, waitMilliseconds, options
const debouncedFunction = debounce(originalFunction, 250)
window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedFunction)
```